# Invokespecial Verify Error: Type is not assignable

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, bytecode, verifyerror

I've modified the line 15 of the bytecode below and changed it form invokevirtual to invokespecial (JAVA 8). Unfortunately I get a verify error ( Bad type on operand stack)

I know that the value of the operand stack must be a subclass of the class specified in the objectref but in this case #18 is Type and not Type$ClassType like the error suggest. Or to say it differently shouldn't the stackmapframe at line 15 have Type and not Type$ClassType in stack[0]? What am I missing?

edit: stackmapframes are the same before and after the change. (in case ASM COMPUTE FRAMES which I used would changed them)

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type$ClassType.toString()Ljava/lang/String; @15: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type$ClassType'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @15
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type$ClassType', 'java/lang/StringBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type', 'com/sun/tools/javac/code/TypeTag' }
  ...     
  Stackmap Table:
append_frame(@71,Object[#108])
same_frame(@85)
same_frame(@121)
```

Here's is the code. Type$ClassType is a direct subclass of Type and com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type$ClassType is the current class which allows us to call a superclass (like Type) with invokespecial

```
    public class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType extends com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type implements
 javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
    ....
    public java.lang.String toString();
        descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
        flags: ACC_PUBLIC
        Code:
          stack=4, locals=2, args_size=1
             0: new           #108                // class java/lang/StringBuilder
             3: dup
             4: invokespecial #17                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
             7: astore_1
             8: aload_0
             9: invokevirtual #13                 // Method com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type$ClassType.getEnclosingType:()Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;
            12: getstatic     #10                 // Field com/sun/tools/javac/code/TypeTag.CLASS:Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/TypeTag;
            15: invokespecial #18                 // Method com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type.hasTag:(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/TypeTag;)Z
            18: ifeq          71
            .....
            StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 3
              frame_type = 252 /* append */
                offset_delta = 71
                locals = [ class java/lang/StringBuilder ]
              frame_type = 13 /* same */
              frame_type = 35 /* same */
```

Comment: there are only a few people that can answer this... hopefully they will come along

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You attempt to execute `invokespecial` on an instance of `Type` (returned by `invokevirtual` @9), while the verifier expects the reference of current class, i.e. `Type$ClassType`.

See JVMS [§4.10.1.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.invokespecial):

> One can validly replace types matching the **current class** and the
>   argument types given in Descriptor on the incoming operand stack with
>   the return type given in Descriptor, yielding the outgoing type state.

Answer (score 5):

`invokespecial` is used to implement either of three things

1. A constructor invocation
2. Invoking a `private` method
3. Doing a `super. …` call

While 1. does not apply here (as the target method’s name is not `<init>`), either of the other cases requires the receiver type to be of the current class or a subclass of it. So even when the method’s declaring class is `Type`, the actual receiver’s type is expected to be assignable to the current class, `Type$ClassType`.

The closest equivalent to what you’ve created with your change, is a `super` invocation, though in Java source code, calling a method via `super` enforces the receiver reference to be the same as `this`, which is intrinsically assignable to the current class.

On the bytecode level, the rules are less restrictive, still, a method invocation allowing to bypass method declarations in your current class or its subclasses is not allowed to be invoked on a type reference which could point to an instance of an entirely unrelated subclass hierarchy, i.e. a `Type` not being a `Type$ClassType`.

The relevant JVMS rule has been cited in [apangin’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55105761/2711488) already.